# My React App functionality is not working on mobiles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, mobile-website

I am new to React and I created my first app and deployed it in netlify.
The link is https://youtubevideosabubakkersiddiq.netlify.app/

When I visit the website in the laptop it is working fine. But when I visit this page in my **mobile** and try to test the functionality it doesnt work at all. The functionality for now is like searching a youtube video cover

- Just copy a youtube link and paste it in the field and click search it will show the cover of that specific video you have searched.
- This works in desktop browsers only.

Anybody has any idea ?

**Note: I am using the Youtube Data API for searching the videos and displaying them**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that youtube has seperate link processing for both desktop and mobile and now figured that and now it is working fine